# Why am I getting different results on a prediction using the same Keras model and input?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

posting here is my last resort cause I can't find anything like it online. I trained a model to classify embeddings into categories (a simple three layer Dense neural network).

Now I want to use the trained model to make predictions in real time, but I discovered that if I input the whole *test* dataframe to the model, get the prediction for say the element number `i`, and compare it to the prediction that I get by inputting just the element number `i` of the *test* data frame into the model, I get different results. This is the code in case I didn't explain it good enough:

```
i = 522
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred_2 = model.predict(X_test.iloc[[i]])

print (f'{np.argmax(y_pred[i])} {np.argmax(y_pred_2)}')

output: 8 5
```

It's like my model is behaving differently if it processes the whole test set in a single run than if it processes a single row at a time. I'm using pandas for the input data.

**EDIT**: More info, the output shapes of `y_pred` and `y_pred_2` are `(603, 10)` and `(1, 10)` respectively, where 10 is the number of classes I have.

Some example values for both predictions, with an arbitrary `i`:

```
y_pred[i]: array([1.3353945e-02, 2.8374636e-09, 1.4435661e-08, 3.4135045e-18,
   7.7986561e-02, 3.7737598e-03, 2.0284578e-10, 2.7154891e-03,
   9.0203673e-01, 1.3346069e-04], dtype=float32)

y_pred_2 = array([[1.1702824e-16, 1.6781385e-37, 2.5281618e-33, 0.0000000e+00,
        2.3075200e-09, 1.0000000e+00, 9.9125501e-35, 6.2606384e-22,
        5.8689110e-14, 2.3486194e-24]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: check the shapes of `y_pred` and `y_pred_2`

Comment: @PaulH they're (603, 10) and (1,10) respectively, as the first one contains the predictions for all 603 rows in the test set

Answer (score 0):

`np.argmax` defaults to the row axis. You're getting the maximum prediction across rows, and you want it across columns. Try:

```
print(f'{np.argmax(y_pred[i], axis=1)} {np.argmax(y_pred_2, axis=1)}')
```

Comment: I'm getting the results as an array of shape (input_samples, classes), so in this case the results are the same for both argmax arguments.

Comment: i don't think that's how it works. what happens if you try my suggestion?

Comment: I get the same results, as the problem is within the y_pred themselves and not the selected class. Both `y_pred` and `y_pred_2` should have the same values but they're way off for some reason...

Comment: can you print `y_pred[i]` and `y_pred_2` and add it to your post?

Comment: I just added some values. It happens with every `i`!